# How to change the index or shape of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I have a data frame of shape 2x3 and I want to change it into 3x2 and then visualize it.

How can I do both?

Here's my code :

```
avg_txn_by_mth = {
    'August': {
        'avg_cnt': txn_by_mth['August']['Count'] / 31,
        'avg_amt': txn_by_mth['August']['Amount'] / txn_by_mth['August']['Count']
    },
    'September': {
        'avg_cnt': txn_by_mth['September']['Count'] / 30, 
        'avg_amt': txn_by_mth['September']['Amount'] / txn_by_mth['September']['Count']
    },
    'October': {
        'avg_cnt': txn_by_mth['October']['Count'] / 31, 
        'avg_amt': txn_by_mth['October']['Amount'] / txn_by_mth['October']['Count']
    }
}

avg_txn_by_mth = pd.DataFrame(avg_txn_by_mth)
avg_txn_by_mth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'August': {'avg_amt': 2.0, 'avg_cnt': 9.67741935483871},
        'October': {'avg_amt': 1.6, 'avg_cnt': 16.129032258064516},
        'September': {'avg_amt': 1.75, 'avg_cnt': 13.333333333333334}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display
           August    October  September
avg_amt  2.000000   1.600000   1.750000
avg_cnt  9.677419  16.129032  13.333333

# transpose
dft = df.T

# display
           avg_amt    avg_cnt
August        2.00   9.677419
October       1.60  16.129032
September     1.75  13.333333

# plot
p = dft.plot()
```

[image]